# With this code I can't get update nothing changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

It's a GridView Update there are no syntax problems.

After updating `((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt")).Text;`  it returns same text nothing changes I can't get the text which I typed in update mode in textbox

example : if I have text - `someText`

in update I typed - `newText`

at the end It returns - `someText`

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) {
    int id = Convert.ToInt32((GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Label1ID") as Label).Text);
    PersonData data = (from x in Domain.Instance.PersonDatas
                                         where x.ID == id
                                         select x).First();

    data.Info = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt")).Text;
    data.Info1 = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt1")).Text;
    data.Info2 = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt2")).Text;

    Domain.Instance.SaveChanges();

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    DatBind();
}
```

there is a property :

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Info">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Info") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LabelInfo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Info") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem could be in the binding the gridview.
You should not be binding your gridview on page load.
It should be like follows

```
 if(!IsPostBack)  /// <<<<<<<<<<
 {
    GridView1.DataSource = yourDataSource;
    GridView1.DataBind();
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Page_Load.  He is re-binding the datasource after updating the underlying data and editindex in the RowUpdating event.

Comment: @jadarnel27, what shekhar mentioned is correct, if he binds data during postback it will ovewrite new values when you issue edit command, btw +1 from me for mentioning about Page_Load binding

Comment: @jadarnel27 if you bind you gridview simply on the page load it will give you the old values :);

Comment: @Shekhar "*if you bind you gridview simply on the page load it will give you the old values*" - I'm aware of that =)  The OP just didn't mention anything about their Page_Load function, or show it.  And they are obtaining the new values incorrectly in the RowUpdating event.

Comment: @jadarnel27, What OP is doing is not wrong, his code will return new values that were entered in TextBox in Edit template. Check MSDN sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx#Y342)

Comment: @rs. Alright, maybe I am confused here.  Apparently I have misunderstood something about the problem.